# Chromecast receiver development using GWT

Tags: android, ios, windows-8, google-cast, chromecast

Our webapp at http://iStoryBooks.co is developed using GWT. We are building Chromecast support on this website. I was wondering if anyone out there has a sample GWT receiver for Chromecast?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We ended up implementing a GWT wrapper for the receive api. Its available at https://github.com/imarvelapps/GWTChromeCast.

Any feedback appreciated.